# PHP $_POST data into Variable

Tags: php, arrays, json, parsing

I have following $_POST data from the form fieldset

```
array(2) { 
   ["item-1"] => 
       array(2) { 
           ["name"]=> string(5) "apple" 
           ["price"]=> string(1) "5" 
       } 
   ["item-2"] => 
       array(2) { 
           ["name"]=> string(6) "orange" 
           ["price"]=> string(1) "2" 
       }
}
```

I want to store this post data into variables using **foreach** such as `$name_1` `$price_1` & `$name_2` `$price_2`

How can I parse this form-data ?

Comment: This seems like a really bad idea, because you may have an unknown number of entries. What exactly is your use-case? Why do you want the variables `$name_1`, `$name_2`, etc.?

Comment: Use an array instead using variables like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Altough I think it's completely unlogical to use variables this way, this can help you out.
It created the variables automatically using the given information..

```
//array with values
$source = [
    'item-1' => [
        'name' => 'apple',
        'price' => '5',
    ],
    'item-2' => [
        'name' => 'orange',
        'price' => '2'
    ]
];

foreach($source as $k=>$array) {
    //get all integer values from the key
    $int = preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', $k);

    //foreach property in $array, create the variable name + the integer number 
    //as a variable and set the value belonging to the key
    foreach($array as $name=>$value) {
        ${$name . '_' . $int} = $value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually this is answer that reflects question the best imo.

Answer (score 0):

```
$i = 1;
foreach($_POST as $data) {
    ${'name_' . $i}  = $data["name"];
    ${'price_' . $i} = $data["price"];
    $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($_POST as $k => $v) {
  $i = +preg_replace('/item-(\d+)/', '$1', $k);
  foreach(array('name', 'price') as $name) {
    $key = "$name_$i";
    $$key = $v[$name];
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this..**

```
<?php
$response = 
array(    
        'item-1' => array(
            2 => array(
                'name' => 'apple',
                'price' => 5
            ),          
        ),
        'item-2' => array(
            2 => array(
                'name' => 'orange',
                'price' => 2
            ),          
        ),
    );



foreach($response as $key =>$value)
{

$k=explode("-",$key);
$keyvalue=end($k);
foreach($value as $result)
{
echo ${'name_' . $keyvalue}=$result['name'];
echo "</br>";
echo ${'price_' . $keyvalue}=$result['price'];
echo "</br>";
}
}
?>
```